# Клик по элементу с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать автоклик по определенной кнопке в JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут ничего сложного. Первое - нужно получить кнопку, к примеру через [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) и вызвать у нее событие [`click`](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events). Для наглядности вызов клика функции поместил в [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), событие, которое происходит когда весь HTML был полностью загружен. И вызвал функцию в [`setTimeout`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) - внутренний таймер-планировщик, который позволяет задавать вызов функции через заданный период времени.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // когда весь HTML загружен

  setTimeout(function() { // таймер-планировщик
    document.getElementById('btn-click').click(); // вызвать клик на кнопку
  }, 2000); // через две секунды

});


function doFunction() { // функция привязанная к клику на кнопку
  alert('I was pressed!');
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-click" onclick="doFunction();">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    button.form.submit();
}
```

А так можете указать сколько раз нажимать каждую секунду

```
window.onload = function(){ var button = document.getElementById('clickButton'), form = button.form;

form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return false;
})

var times = 100;   //Here put the number of times you want to auto submit
(function submit(){
    if(times == 0) return;
    form.submit();
    times--;
    setTimeout(submit, 1000);   //Each second
})(); 

}
```