# Можно ли нажать на элемент button на странице не видя его?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

При использовании такого способа:

```
IWebElement[] FollowButton = Browser.FindElements(By.ClassName("sqdOP")).ToArray();
FollowButton[0].Click();
```

Выдает подобную ошибку:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Сообщение = element click intercepted: Element <button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (942, 15).
 Other element would receive the click: <div class="MWDvN buoMu nfCOa">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
  Источник = WebDriver
```

Comment: А вы попробуйте кликнуть в консоли браузера через JS. Если получится, значит можно.

Comment: Там нет события onclick. Или есть еще способ через js нажать?

Comment: [Конечно есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660526/373567)